# Multiple ModalPopUpExtenders on one page inside a UserControl

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have 1 ModalPopupExtender inside a UserControl. Everything works great until I start adding the same usercontrol to the page. I am getting this error message in the javascript console::

> *Message: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Two components with the same id 'MPE1' can't be added to the application.*

I understand the error, it obvious that the framework wants unique IDs. What I can't figure out is how to give them unique name. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please post examples of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brian, thanks but this is in .NET 2.0.

The simple way to solve this is to just remove the tag "BehaviorID". That is the option I am going with now, I just hope in the future I won't have to use JS to call any of the popups.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using .NET 4 with a ClientIDMode of static?  That would cause the issue, though with the default or a predictive option, this should work... check the client footprint, to see if all of the ID's are MPE1 or how that's being done.  It should be uc1_MPE1.  If you have two UC's with the same ID (or null ID), that would cause the issue.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Do as explained by *ssparacio* and remove the BehaviorID tag. You can do this provided that you do not need to make client-side calls to the control.
2. Assign BehaviourID a unique value during Page_Init. A good choice would be the ID of the user-control in which the control is defined.